# Upgrading dojo 1.3.2 to 1.4.x

Tags: javascript, dojo

Up till now my system used dojo 1.3.2 successfully. I have many Javascript files with our own declared classes which are combined together using shrinksafe to a single Javascript file.

I tried to upgrade to dojo 1.4.x (I tried several minor versions). I used the build system with a layer file with all the `dojo.require()`'s I use (the same one I used to build the 1.3.2 version.). The build process seems to be successful.

Unfortunately, I cannot succeed in bringing the system on the air. Firebug throws exceptions such as `... is not a constructor` for my declared classes, and `mixin #0 is null`.

Please help !

Comment: See if all bases are actually dojo.require()'d properly.

Answer (score 2):

These error point to 2 things:

1) Make sure you have a full src build of dojo.

2) The signature of dojo.declare changed in 1.4:

previously you will probably have had the following declaration for a class with no inheritance:

```
dojo.declare("myNamespace.classA", [], {...
```

In 1.4 the empty array of inherited classes will break a custom build. You should upgrade your code to the new signature of dojo.declare:

```
dojo.declare("myNamespace.classA", null, {...
```